# Excel compare and copy paste between workbooks sheets code deletes existing values if comparison between workbook sheets is not found

Tags: excel, vba

This code compares one column cells values of two different workbooks sheets and if the column cells values match it copies preselected columns cells information from respective column which was compared from source workbook sheet to destination workbook sheet ( they are noted in the code as Book2(source) and book1(destination)). The code works fine apart from the fact that if a value is not available in source workbook sheet then it basically deletes the existing values from destination workbook sheets columns. Id like a way to solve this without having my existing data deleted. Ive added pictures to explain. The data Was previously available in C1 and D1 in Book 1, but since from A column A1 is not available in Book2 it deletes the existing values from C1 and D1 in Book1, This should not happen. Ive tried adapting specialcells and if range is empty to not change the values, but it did not work and it still deletes the existing values
Thank you The credit for the code is from Mr. Excel forum i think, I do not remember who exactly now. Thanks for suggestions and help

[image: Book1]

[image: Book2]

```vb
Sub MultiLookupDataSpecial()
     ' Define constants.

    Const SRC_FILE_NAME As String = "Book2.xlsm"
    Const SRC_WORKSHEET_ID As Variant = 1
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMNS As String = "B"
    Const SRC_VALUE_COLUMNS As String = "N,AU,AW"
    
    Const DST_FILE_NAME As String = "Book1.xlsm"
    Const DST_WORKSHEET_ID As Variant = 1
    Const DST_LOOKUP_COLUMNS As String = "B"
    Const DST_VALUE_COLUMNS As String = "N,AU,AW"
    
    Const LOOKUP_DELIMITER As String = "@@"
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = "C:\Users\R Work\Desktop\"
    
    ' Reference the Source range.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & SRC_FILE_NAME)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_WORKSHEET_ID)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    If sws.Range("A1").Text <> "" Then
       With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
          srCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
          Set srg = .Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
       End With
    End If
    ' Write the values from the Source Lookup column
    ' to arrays of the jagged Source Lookup array.
    
    Dim slCols() As String: slCols = Split(SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMNS, ",")
    Dim nlUpper As Long: nlUpper = UBound(slCols)
    
    Dim slJag() As Variant: ReDim slJag(0 To nlUpper)
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To nlUpper
        slJag(n) = srg.Columns(slCols(n)).Value
    Next n
    
    ' Write the unique values from the Source Lookup array to the 'keys'
    ' of a dictionary and the associated rows to its 'items'.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long, sString As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sString = CStr(slJag(0)(sr, 1))
        For n = 1 To nlUpper
            sString = sString & LOOKUP_DELIMITER & CStr(slJag(n)(sr, 1))
        Next n
        If Not dict.Exists(sString) Then dict(sString) = sr
    Next sr
        
    Erase slJag ' data is in the dictionary
        
    ' Write the values from the Source Value columns to arrays
    ' of the jagged Source Value array.
    
    Dim svCols() As String: svCols = Split(SRC_VALUE_COLUMNS, ",")
    Dim nvUpper As Long: nvUpper = UBound(svCols)
    
    Dim svJag() As Variant: ReDim svJag(0 To nvUpper)
    
    For n = 0 To nvUpper
        svJag(n) = srg.Columns(svCols(n)).Value
    Next n
        
    ' Reference the Destination range.
        
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & DST_FILE_NAME)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_WORKSHEET_ID)
    
    Dim drg As Range, drCount As Long
    
    With dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        drCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
        Set drg = .Resize(drCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Write the values from the Destination Lookup column
    ' to arrays of the jagged Source Lookup array.
    
    Dim dlCols() As String: dlCols = Split(DST_LOOKUP_COLUMNS, ",")
    
    Dim dlJag() As Variant: ReDim dlJag(0 To nlUpper)
    
    For n = 0 To nlUpper
        dlJag(n) = drg.Columns(dlCols(n)).Value
    Next n
    
    ' Copy empty arrays for the Desetination Value columns
    ' to the jagged Destination Value array.
    
    Dim dvCols() As String: dvCols = Split(DST_VALUE_COLUMNS, ",")
    
    Dim dvJag() As Variant: ReDim dvJag(0 To nvUpper)
    
    Dim dvHelp() As Variant: ReDim dvHelp(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    For n = 0 To nvUpper
        dvJag(n) = dvHelp
    Next n

    Erase dvHelp

    ' Comparing the Destination Lookup array with the dictionary,
    ' write the matching data from the arrays of the Source Value array
    ' to the arrays of the Destination Value array.

    Dim dr As Long, dString As String
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        dString = CStr(dlJag(0)(dr, 1))
        For n = 1 To nlUpper
            dString = dString & LOOKUP_DELIMITER & CStr(dlJag(n)(dr, 1))
        Next n
        If dict.Exists(dString) Then
            For n = 0 To nvUpper
                dvJag(n)(dr, 1) = svJag(n)(dict(dString), 1)
            Next n
        End If
    Next dr
    
    ' Write the values from the arrays of the Destination Value array
    ' to the Destination Value columns.
    
    For n = 0 To nvUpper
        drg.Columns(dvCols(n)).Value = dvJag(n)
        
    Next n
    
    ' Save and close the workbooks.
    
    ' dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    ' swb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
     ' Inform.
        '   With Rows(2)
       ' .Replace What:="Column3", Replacement:="Start Date", LookAt:=xlWhole
         '  .Replace What:="Column4", Replacement:="Deadline", LookAt:=xlWhole
          '   .Replace What:="Column5", Replacement:="Liberre", LookAt:=xlWhole
         ' End With
    MsgBox "Data looked up.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "it deletes the existing values from C1 and D1", looking to the pictures you show, do you mean "C1 and E1"? Otherwise, I cannot understand your question. At the first glance (not related to the problem you have), instead of `If Not dict.Exists(sString) Then dict(sString) = sr` you can simple use `dict(sString) = sr`. A `dictionary` 'knows' to not double an existing key...

Comment: Then, can you better describe in which circumstances you do not want it to clear existing? For instance, **to overwrite only in case of no empty strings to be copied**, would it be a good understanding of what you want?

Comment: Hi , Yes I meant E1, And yes, it should only overwrite incase it finds a match, otherwise if in source book a match is not found it should not overwrite the currently existing values in the destination workbook. As pictures portray it indeed deletes the existing values if no match is found and I lose some data :/

Comment: As in If DATA1 exists in both workbooks it should indeed copy paste new values from source wb ws, but incase DATA1 exists in destination workbook, but not in Source then it should not delete the already existing data in destination workbook

Comment: What do you mean by "a match"? I couldn't see in your code a part looking for a match... it copies from one sheet to another, without checking anything... I could see now that a new comment appeared when I was writing. But I asked about something else. I mean, since your existing code does not search for any match, overwriting **only for not empty strings to be copied** wouldn't it be a simple solution to adapt the code?

Comment: Do you really supplied examples (pictures) from the range to be processed by the above code? I looks to process columns `N, AU, AW` and you show columns `A, C, D(E)`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You are creating `dvJag(n)` as empty array and only filling with matching values eg`If dict.Exists(dString) Then` so the non matching will remain blank. Initialise `dvJag` with existing data or use an else clause to fill with existing data.

Comment: I suppose my question was not as clear, sorry guys..

Comment: It does actually look for a match, it compares the values in selected columns from two workbooks worksheets using array and dictionaries, not fully familiar with the concept

Comment: And to answer @FaneDuru, no , its just an example pictures, but I did use the same code for the example when testing if it would work for my huge data

Comment: Just the letters in this part changed : Const SRC_FILE_NAME As String = "Book2.xlsm"
    Const SRC_WORKSHEET_ID As Variant = 1
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMNS As String = "A"
    Const SRC_VALUE_COLUMNS As String = "C,E"
    
    Const DST_FILE_NAME As String = "Book1.xlsm"
    Const DST_WORKSHEET_ID As Variant = 1
    Const DST_LOOKUP_COLUMNS As String = "A"
    Const DST_VALUE_COLUMNS As String = "C,E"

Comment: We may be confused only looking to your code, if you do not explain (in words) what **exactly** you try doing... If you want confusing us with pictures not related to the code you show, I am afraid that it is difficult to understand what's happening. For instance, only looking to the variables naming, `LOOKUP_COLUMNS` should mean a kink of matching (per column B), but I cannot see anything in B:B to be checked...

Comment: Im sorry, I will post another question later on with the same issue using accurate images and included images with before the code was run and after

Comment: I am afraid that you did not understand too much about your obligation to supply a **reproductible example**... If you do not help us to understand what exactly you need, it is difficult to be halped.

Comment: Please give me some time to create an accurate question for you and i will make sure to tag you there so you could have a look, thank you

Comment: Change line `dvJag(n) = drg.Columns(dvCols(n)).Value 'DVHELP`

Comment: @FaneDuru his code is about N,AU,AW columns but his example is about A, C, E columns so it is easily visible. His problem is that the ranges get the new values with an empty initialized array (so the previous value becomes lost when it isn't found anymore). CDP is correct (if I'm not mistaken) with filling the array with the old values first. From what I could see, OP's code already only fills in a new value if it does exist.